# Munin dynamic graph zoom (dynazoom) not working (Nginx, PHP-FPM)

Tags: nginx, debian, php-fpm, munin

Debian 7.5
Nginx/1.6.0
PHP 5.6.0RC2 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Jul 11 2014 08:17:52)
Munin v2.0.21-2

I been searching all over the net for a few days for answers to my problem but it seems like no one knows what to do about it. I got Munin up and running but Munin dynamic graph zoom (dynazoom) is not working it seems like a problem with cgi I have tested Munin with lighttpd and apache using spawnfcgi and everything works fine but not with php5-fpm. The graphs on the zoom screen show up but not with php5-fpm it just shows a a broken image link just like this image http://serversupportforum.de/forum/attachments/monitoring/4901d1373968950-munin-dynazoom-funktioniert-nicht-1592281191.png "Munin dynamic graph zoom (dynazoom)"

A lot of people nowadays are using Nginx with php-fpm so i think this will be a lot of help to tons of people. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645812/munin-dynamic-graph-zoom-dynazoom-not-working-centos6-nginx-php-fpm

Here is my nginx config file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

Here is my Vhost file:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }

     location /munin/ {
        alias /var/cache/munin/www/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
    }

        location /munin/static/ {
        alias /etc/munin/static/;
        index index.html index.htm index.php;
}

        location ^~ munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/ {
            fastcgi_pass   unix:/tmp/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
}


        location /nginx_status {
            stub_status on;
            access_log   off;
            allow 127.0.0.1;
            allow 192.168.56.1;
        deny all;
            }


    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    #error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    #location = /50x.html {
    #   root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    #   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    #   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
    #
    #   # With php5-cgi alone:
    #   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    #   # With php5-fpm:
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #   deny all;
    #}
}


# another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
#
#server {
#   listen 8000;
#   listen somename:8080;
#   server_name somename alias another.alias;
#   root html;
#   index index.html index.htm;
#
#   location / {
#       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#   }
#}
```

The Munin config file:

```
# Example configuration file for Munin, generated by 'make build'

# The next three variables specifies where the location of the RRD
# databases, the HTML output, logs and the lock/pid files.  They all
# must be writable by the user running munin-cron.  They are all
# defaulted to the values you see here.
#
dbdir   /var/lib/munin
htmldir /var/cache/munin/www
logdir /var/log/munin
rundir  /var/run/munin

# Where to look for the HTML templates
#
tmpldir /etc/munin/templates

# Where to look for the static www files
#
staticdir /etc/munin/static

# temporary cgi files are here. note that it has to be writable by 
# the cgi user (usually nobody or httpd).
#
cgitmpdir /var/lib/munin/cgi-tmp

# (Exactly one) directory to include all files from.
includedir /etc/munin/munin-conf.d

# You can choose the time reference for "DERIVE" like graphs, and show
# "per minute", "per hour" values instead of the default "per second"
#
graph_period second

# Graphics files are generated either via cron or by a CGI process.
# See http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2 for more
# documentation.
# Since 2.0, munin-graph has been rewritten to use the cgi code. 
# It is single threaded *by design* now.
#
graph_strategy cron

# munin-cgi-graph is invoked by the web server up to very many times at the
# same time.  This is not optimal since it results in high CPU and memory
# consumption to the degree that the system can thrash.  Again the default is
# 6.  Most likely the optimal number for max_cgi_graph_jobs is the same as
# max_graph_jobs.
#
#munin_cgi_graph_jobs 6

# If the automatic CGI url is wrong for your system override it here:
#
#cgiurl_graph /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph

# max_size_x and max_size_y are the max size of images in pixel.
# Default is 4000. Do not make it too large otherwise RRD might use all
# RAM to generate the images.
# 
max_size_x 4000
max_size_y 4000

# HTML files are normally generated by munin-html, no matter if the
# files are used or not. You can change this to on-demand generation
# by following the instructions in http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/CgiHowto2
# 
# Notes: 
# - moving to CGI for HTML means you cannot have graph generated by cron.
# - cgi html has some bugs, mostly you still have to launch munin-html by hand
# 
html_strategy cron

# munin-update runs in parallel.
#
# The default max number of processes is 16, and is probably ok for you.
#
# If set too high, it might hit some process/ram/filedesc limits.
# If set too low, munin-update might take more than 5 min.
#
# If you want munin-update to not be parallel set it to 0.
#
max_processes 16

# RRD updates are per default, performed directly on the rrd files.
# To reduce IO and enable the use of the rrdcached, uncomment it and set it to
# the location of the socket that rrdcached uses.
#
#rrdcached_socket /var/run/rrdcached.sock

# Drop somejuser@fnord.comm and anotheruser@blibb.comm an email everytime
# something changes (OK -> WARNING, CRITICAL -> OK, etc)
#contact.someuser.command mail -s "Munin notification" somejuser@fnord.comm
#contact.anotheruser.command mail -s "Munin notification" anotheruser@blibb.comm
#
# For those with Nagios, the following might come in handy. In addition,
# the services must be defined in the Nagios server as well.
#contact.nagios.command /usr/bin/send_nsca nagios.host.comm -c /etc/nsca.conf

# a simple host tree
[localhost.localdomain]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes

#
# A more complex example of a host tree
#
## First our "normal" host.
# [fii.foo.com]
#       address foo
#
## Then our other host...
# [fay.foo.com]
#       address fay
#
## IPv6 host. note that the ip adress has to be in brackets
# [ip6.foo.com]
#       address [2001::1234:1]
#
## Then we want totals...
# [foo.com;Totals] #Force it into the "foo.com"-domain...
#       update no   # Turn off data-fetching for this "host".
#
#   # The graph "load1". We want to see the loads of both machines...
#   # "fii=fii.foo.com:load.load" means "label=machine:graph.field"
#       load1.graph_title Loads side by side
#       load1.graph_order fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#
#   # The graph "load2". Now we want them stacked on top of each other.
#       load2.graph_title Loads on top of each other
#       load2.dummy_field.stack fii=fii.foo.com:load.load fay=fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load2.dummy_field.draw AREA # We want area instead the default LINE2.
#       load2.dummy_field.label dummy # This is needed. Silly, really.
#
#   # The graph "load3". Now we want them summarised into one field
#       load3.graph_title Loads summarised
#       load3.combined_loads.sum fii.foo.com:load.load fay.foo.com:load.load
#       load3.combined_loads.label Combined loads # Must be set, as this is
#                                                 # not a dummy field!
#
## ...and on a side note, I want them listen in another order (default is
## alphabetically)
#
# # Since [foo.com] would be interpreted as a host in the domain "com", we
# # specify that this is a domain by adding a semicolon.
# [foo.com;]
#       node_order Totals fii.foo.com fay.foo.com
#
```

The munin-node config file:

```
#
# Example config-file for munin-node
#

log_level 4
log_file /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
pid_file /var/run/munin/munin-node.pid

background 1
setsid 1

user root
group root

# This is the timeout for the whole transaction.
# Units are in sec. Default is 15 min
#
# global_timeout 900

# This is the timeout for each plugin.
# Units are in sec. Default is 1 min
#
# timeout 60

# Regexps for files to ignore
ignore_file [\#~]$
ignore_file DEADJOE$
ignore_file \.bak$
ignore_file %$
ignore_file \.dpkg-(tmp|new|old|dist)$
ignore_file \.rpm(save|new)$
ignore_file \.pod$

# Set this if the client doesn't report the correct hostname when
# telnetting to localhost, port 4949
#
#host_name localhost.localdomain

# A list of addresses that are allowed to connect.  This must be a
# regular expression, since Net::Server does not understand CIDR-style
# network notation unless the perl module Net::CIDR is installed.  You
# may repeat the allow line as many times as you'd like

allow ^127\.0\.0\.1$
allow ^::1$

# If you have installed the Net::CIDR perl module, you can use one or more
# cidr_allow and cidr_deny address/mask patterns.  A connecting client must
# match any cidr_allow, and not match any cidr_deny.  Note that a netmask
# *must* be provided, even if it's /32
#
# Example:
#
# cidr_allow 127.0.0.1/32
# cidr_allow 192.0.2.0/24
# cidr_deny  192.0.2.42/32

# Which address to bind to;
host *
# host 127.0.0.1

# And which port
port 4949
```

Answer (score 8):

You have wrong `fastcgi_pass` parameter, it should pass requests to spawn-fcgi just as [munin's wiki says](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/MuninConfigurationMasterCGI#nginx) not to php-fpm.

For Ubuntu/Debian:

```
sudo apt-get install spawn-fcgi
spawn-fcgi -s /var/run/munin/fcgi-graph.sock -U www-data -u www-data -g www-data /usr/lib/munin/cgi/munin-cgi-graph
```

And dont forget to fix nginx location and restart it afterwards:

```
    location ^~ /munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph/ {
        access_log off;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/munin-cgi/munin-cgi-graph)(.*);
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/munin/fcgi-graph.sock;
        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Comment: I also needed to install ``libcgi-fast-perl``.

Comment: This works great! <3